# typescript upgrade 1.8.10 to 2.9.2 and 4.6.4 build error

Tags: c#, typescript, npm, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have an angular application, using typescript `1.8.10` and working fine. I  like to try and upgrade typescript from `1.8.10` to `2.9.2`. Once I change this setting in package.json and run npm install I get a lot of errors. Is there anything I need to do to use this version?

Version 2.9.2 Error

> Severity   Code    Description File    Project Line    Suppression State
> Error       Build:',' expected. C:\WebProjects\ITF\Web\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts

Update I tried to update typescript to 4.6.4 but I am getting a different error about the same file

Version 4.6.4 Error

> Severity   Code    Description File    Project Line    Suppression State
> Error       Build:Invalid 'reference' directive syntax. C:\WebProjects\ITF\Web\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts

Comment: I'm curious: If you're going to upgrade, why not go all the way to the current version?

Comment: I just wanted to take little steps but I would like to get the current version.

Comment: I think I'd just bite the bullet and jump all the way. :-)

Comment: @t-j-crowder I tried the current version 4.6.4 but I am getting a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invalid 'reference'` show when the package path is missing, or something's wrong with it. Deleting the entire `node_modules` folder and reinstall them with your package manager (npm or yarn).

```
npm install
```

If that doesn't work, I would suggest you to update your dependencies.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/10097